# How can I properly create multilingual metadata in pdftk

Tags: pdf, pdftk

pdftk let's you set the title of a PDF with the following command:

```
pdftk input.pdf update_info metadata.txt output output.pdf
```

However, if I use special characters in the metadata.txt file (such as German characters or chinese characters) then it doesn't seem to work.

Here's an example of changing the title:

```
InfoBegin
InfoKey: Title
InfoValue: Fingerspitzengefühl is a German term.
```

However, the PDF ends up with a strange character for the ü

In the [documentation of pdftk](https://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-man-page/#dest-op-update-info) it says that non-ASCII characters should be encoded as XML numerical entities. However, I Googled myself silly but couldn't find anything that works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best reference I've found is [Numerical Character Reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_character_reference), which is applicable to XML (and XHTML and SGML).

This is generally used to represent characters that are not directly encodable.

In your case, the character is U+252, `ü` which can be substituted with `&#252;` (Decimal), `&0374;` (Octal), or `&#xFC;` (Hexidecimal).

Using a decimal reference, your file should be encoded as:

```
InfoBegin
InfoKey: Title
InfoValue: Fingerspitzengef&#252;hl is a German term.
```

**Note:**

If you're on 'Nix, you can use `recode` to encode the file.

```
% cat metadata.txt | recode ..xml
```

Comment: that works for German indeed! I haven't checked Chinese or other characters yet, but it's blazing fast and the details make sense!

Answer (score 2):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70757904/19418090) seems better as there is no need to install extra tools. Instead, it uses PDFtk’s built-in flag `dump_data_utf8` and `update_info_utf8`:

```bash
pdftk input.pdf update_info_utf8 metadata.txt output output.pdf
```

It works perfect for Chinese.