# pdftk update_info command raising a warning which I don't understand

Tags: windows, powershell, pdftk

I'm trying to use the `update_info` command in order to add some bookmarks to an existing pdf's metadata using `pdftk` and powershell.

I first dump the metadata into a file as follows:

`pdftk .\test.pdf dump_data > test.info`

Then, I edit the `test.info` file by adding the bookmarks, I believe I am using the right syntax. I save the `test.info` file and attempt to write the metadata to a new pdf file using `update_info`:

`pdftk test.pdf update_info test.info output out.pdf`

Unfortunately, I get a warning as follows:

> pdftk Warning: unexpected case 1 in LoadDataFile(); continuing

`out.pdf` is generated, but contains no bookmarks. Just to be sure it is not a syntax problem, I also ran it without editing the metadata file, by simply overwriting the same metadata. I still got the same warning.

Why is this warning occurring? Why are no bookmarks getting written to my resulting pdf?

Comment: The warning means an input line was not understood and skipped (yes, It is very cryptic). Can you post a minimal example of your bookmark metadata? See e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17065/add-and-edit-bookmarks-to-a-pdf-file to make sure you use the right syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using redirection in that fashion

`pdftk .\test.pdf dump_data > test.info`

will cause this known problem by building wrong file structure, so change to

```
pdftk .\test.pdf dump_data output test.info
```

In addition check your alterations are correctly balanced (and no unusual characters) then save the edited output file in the same encoding.

Note:- you may need to consider

Use `dump_data_utf8` and `update_info_utf8` in order to properly display characters in scripts other than Latin (e. g. oriental CJK)

Answer (score 0):

I used `pdftk --help >pdftk-help.txt` to find the answer.

With credit to the previous answer, the following creates a text file of the information parameters: `pdftk aaa.pdf dump_data output info.txt`

Edit the info.txt file as needed.

The pdftk update_info option creates a new pdf file, leaving the original pdf untouched.  Use: `pdftk aaa.pdf update_info info.txt output bbb.pdf`